# cant read selected item data in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, listboxitem

hi i loaded some data to my datatemplate as you can see in image i have this data:
ItemNumber is : 0
ItemNumber is : 1
ItemNumber is : 2
ItemNumber is : 3
...
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTMEh.png)
but when i want read data i get only
ItemNumber is : 0
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPE4N.png)
where is the problem?

```
private void lvDataBinding_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(lvDataBinding.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lvDataBinding.Items.CurrentItem));
            ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);
            DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
            TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("txtTitle", myContentPresenter);
            Console.WriteLine("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: "
                + myTextBlock.Text);
        }
```

and i can find selectedItem index by this codes:

```
 private void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxItem lbi = sender as ListBoxItem;
            lbi.IsSelected = true;
            selectedItemIndex = lvDataBinding.SelectedIndex;
        }
        private void ListBoxItem_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lvDataBinding.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }
```

update:

```
 <ListView  Name="lvDataBinding" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,175" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="lvDataBinding_SelectionChanged">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
                                    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseLeave"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="TabIndex" Value="-1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
                                </Style>

                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Metro:MetroCanvasGrid Background="#f5f6fa" TabIndex="-1" Focusable="False">
                                        <StackPanel Margin="1,1,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#ffffff" Height="50">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="..\Resources\Delete.png" Cursor="Hand">
                                                        <Image.InputBindings>
                                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" />
                                                        </Image.InputBindings>
                                                    </Image>

                                                    <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="..\Resources\Edit.png" Cursor="Hand">
                                                        <Image.InputBindings>
                                                            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.EditCommand}"/>
                                                        </Image.InputBindings>
                                                    </Image>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" Foreground="#7c7f84" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
               Margin="0,5,5,27"/>
                                                <TextBlock Name="txtContent" Foreground="#7c7f84" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Content}"
               Margin="0,27,5,5"/>
                                            </Grid>

                                        </StackPanel>


                                    </Metro:MetroCanvasGrid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: if its a listbox first few lines of ur code make no sense or at-least are useless/extra codes(if u trying to get the selected item)

Comment: and why didnt u add ur xaml ?

Comment: and the textblocks inside your datatemplate , do they have bindings ?

Comment: @Kajbo i want read selected items data

Comment: @zackraiyan i updated my post please check again

Comment: so u want to get the values of the textblocks inside listview right ?

Comment: @zackraiyan yes

Comment: check out my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better way to access an element within `DataTemplate`

```
 public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
if (depObj != null)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
   {
       DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

       if (child != null && child is T)
           yield return (T)child;

       foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
           yield return childOfChild;
   }
 }
}
```

Now assuming u want to access a textblock from the dataTemplate :

```
  foreach (var txtblk in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(this))
 {
 if (txtblk.Name == "txtTitle")
 {
    ////do what u want
  }
 }
```

**UPDATE**

To get the selected item only , use :

```
 var selectedItems = MyListView.SelectedItems;
foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in selectedItems)
{
//codes here
}
```

Comment: tnx but now i have another problem, i want get values just for selected item when clicked on my button, your code get all items values.

Comment: i don't follow ? my code will only access the textblock named `txtTitle` , isn't it what u want ?

Comment: if you see my first image you can see that i have some items that each item have 2 button (edit / delete) so i want when user click on edit i get current items values not all items

Comment: `current item values` what does that mean ?? can u give an example ?

Comment: problem is here that current item not change

Comment: re-check my answer, maybe tha's what you are looking for ?

Comment: tnx very much exactly what i want. my problem solved